# Ordering using 2D dynamic array

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Assignment exercise that puzzles me:

We have an array of `n` integers in random order and the exercise requires us to sort them using the method specified below.

First we put the integers in rows following two rules:

1. we place integer a on top of integer b only if a < b
2. else we place integer a in a new row

Those 2 rules are used to sort the array.  When we finish applying the rules, we pick the smaller visible integer, one at a time until they are sorted.

The exercise requires the use of 3 arrays:

1. `data[1...n]` which contains the numbers to be sorted
2. `column[1...n,1...]`
3. `number[1..n]` which represents the total number of integers on each column

For example, if

```
data = [3,2,12,8]
```

Then `column` would be:

```
column[1,1] = 3
column[2,1] = 2
column[1,2] = 12
column[2,2] = 8
```

And `number` would be `[2,2]`

I am trying to make a loop (keep in mind that the pseudocode in english might be different than the one i am learning in my natural language)

```
for counter=1 to n 
    number[counter]:=0;
end for

for counter=1 to n
    a := 1;
    b := 1;

    if data[counter] < column[a,number[b]] or number[b]=0 then
        number[b] := number[b] + 1;
        column[a,number[b]] := data[counter];
    else 
        a:=a+1;
        b:=b+1;
    end if
end for
```

But there are plenty of mistakes with this code. Could someone try to explain where I am wrong with the logic?

Comment: Another question would be, should I be discouraged if I can solve easy algorithms? Should I give up? Is algorithm solving something you can learn? Is it a matter of experience? After spending a good 7-8 hours without success should I try tommorow with a clearer mind?

Comment: Before trying to analyze the pseudocode, try understanding *why* the algorithm has the steps it does?  What does arranging values in this way let you do?  *Why* does it work?

Comment: my problem is that it doesn't work. and I can't think straight anymore to figure out why.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?  Are you drawing it out?

Comment: yes. I am writing on paper the values of the variables, how they change on each loop or if and it doesn't work. However when I fix something it breaks something else. Anyway i am going to get back at it tommorow. going to bed now.

Comment: Consider adding an inner loop that keeps going until `data[counter]` is actually added somewhere...

Comment: the basic structure is just fine, but really going through this by hand you don't notice that you mistakenly reinitialize a,b on every pass through the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many `rows` you will end up using, you need to use a growable datastructure to represent your `rows`, so use a list. Second, since the `rows` are stacking the numbers, each row should be a stack. Like

```
List<Stack<Integer>> rows = new ArrayList<Stack<Integer>>();
```

then your algorithm will end up being O(n^2). You will loop through your input and add them to the rows as you go

```
for(int i: input){
   boolean done = false;
   for(int x=0; x < rows.size() && ! done; i++)
     if(row.peep() > i){
       row.add(i);
       done = true;
     }
   if(!done)
     row.add(i);
}
```

When you are done filling the rows, the next step is to read the integers back. You should be able to take it from here.